# How to include javascript in a single wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I know this is not nice at all, but for a customer I have to include an iframe into a single wordpress site or post, which has to resize responsive with a resizer-script (javascript).

Including the iframe works without problems, but the script, which should be called by: 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>` won't open. I checked the source after including it via text-Mode (again not how I would usually would have done this kind of stuff...) and realised that WP put the whole line in comments.

Any suggestion what can be done?

Comment: Without a [mcve], not much.

Answer (score 1):

This is just off the top of my head so my apologies if I am off the mark.

1) Have you tried enqueueing the script inside your theme or (hopefully rather) your child theme's *function.php* file? [Read more...](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

2) Try putting all the code within *iframeResizer.min.js* inside a plugin like [Scripts 'n Styles](https://wordpress.org/plugins/scripts-n-styles/).

3) Perhaps the reason your script is not working is because it needs to be added to the website which is being displayed by the iframe?

Other than that I wouldn't be able to be of much further help without seeing a *debug.log* file or a list of *console errors*

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problematic part is, that I cannot edit the functions etc (it's complicated xD" ). And yes, the second part of the resizer is part of the iframe. Wordpress just keeps comments out my code :/

Answer (score 0):

upload "iframeResizer.min.js" in "js" folder in current active  theme.

add below line in header.php file before wp_head(); in your current active theme.

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/iframeResizer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: then wouldn't the code be overwritten when he updates his theme? Sorry I'm playing devil's advocate.